# Why are SF Symbols not aligned correctly?

Tags: swiftui, sf-symbols

I'm working with creating custom SF Symbols and I've come across a peculiar behavior: symbols get resized and centered vertically, but not horizontally.

For example, I would like to lay our four quarters of a circle in a ZStack, each with a different color, so they form a circle. Here you can see the expected result on the left and actual result on the right:

[image: Left: expected result, a circle. Right: actual result.]

Here is the bare-bones project **with the four custom SF Symbols attached**: https://github.com/Cecile-Lebleu/Custom-SF-Symbols-issue

I've generated the SF Symbols from Figma using [this plugin](https://www.figma.com/community/plugin/1207724751253683840/sf-symbol-creator). When importing the symbols into the SF Symbols app or in XCode Assets, they are displayed in their correct positions:

[image: Screenshot from SF Symbols app.]

Comment: Your sf symbols are just the shape itself you need them to be the size of the circle so the shapes are in place. All your images should be the exact same square size and all the shapes should be in their position based on a square.

Comment: I was able to get the desired result by adding a rectangle over the full size of the symbol. Then, using `.foregroundStyle(.red, .clear)` to make the rectangle transparent. I updated the repo linked above.

Answer (score -1):

I noticed that you didn't include the source for the image, so I've created an example using a circle. The crucial aspect here is the use of negative padding. Essentially, this technique allows the child view to exceed its originally proposed size.

Below, you'll find the code and the corresponding image illustrating this concept:

```
VStack(spacing: 0) {
        HStack(spacing: 0) {
            ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
                Image(systemName: "circle")
                    .resizable()
                    .foregroundStyle(.green)
                    .padding(-10)
            }
            ZStack(alignment: .topTrailing) {
                Image(systemName: "circle")
                    .resizable()
                    .foregroundStyle(.red)
                    .padding(-10)
            }
        }
        HStack(spacing: 0) {
            ZStack(alignment: .bottomLeading) {
                Image(systemName: "circle")
                    .resizable()
                    .foregroundStyle(.yellow)
                
                    .padding(-10)
            }
            ZStack(alignment: .bottomTrailing) {
                Image(systemName: "circle")
                    .resizable()
                    .foregroundStyle(.orange)
                
                    .padding(-10)
            }
        }
    }
    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
```

[image]

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for. If you look at the question, you'll see the intended result: a single full circle made up of four quarters of circles, using custom SF symbols, not the built-in circle. And you'll also find the repository linked, where the custom symbols are attached.

Answer (score -2):

I was able to get the desired result by adding a rectangle over the full size of the symbol. Then, using `.foregroundStyle(.red, .clear)` to make the rectangle transparent. I updated the repo: https://github.com/Cecile-Lebleu/Custom-SF-Symbols-issue